# Selenium I can't send text in field. sendkeys didn't work

Tags: java, selenium

I have this code:

```
 <TD style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; WIDTH: 100px" vAlign=top><LABEL class=REQUIRED_FIELD_LABEL>Identify Number </LABEL>
<OBJECT onblur=ftMaskEdit_NumerDOOnBlur(this) style="background-color: #dddddd; width: 100%; display: block; font-family: TAHOMA; margin-bottom: 1px; height: 20px; visibility: visible; font-size: 11px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" id=ftMaskEdit_1_NUMERDO class=FORM_TEXT_BOX classid=clsid:C932BA85-4374-101B-A56C-00AA003668DC VIEWASTEXT GroupID="PelneDaneWsp"><PARAM NAME="_ExtentX" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="_ExtentY" VALUE="50271"><PARAM NAME="_Version" VALUE="393216"><PARAM NAME="BorderStyle" VALUE="1"><PARAM NAME="ClipMode" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="MousePointer" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="Appearance" VALUE="1"><PARAM NAME="BackColor" VALUE="-2147483643"><PARAM NAME="ForeColor" VALUE="-2147483640"><PARAM NAME="PromptInclude" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="AllowPrompt" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="AutoTab" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="HideSelection" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="Enabled" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="MaxLength" VALUE="64"><PARAM NAME="OLEDragMode" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="OLEDropMode" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="Mask" VALUE=">???######"><PARAM NAME="PromptChar" VALUE="_"></OBJECT></TD>
```

On the webpage is a text box where I can enter text manually. In this text the first,second and third positions must be a letters, and next 6 positions must be numbers eg. "ABC111111", "BBB222222".
When i click on element focus is different.
in my code:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.id("ftMaskEdit_1_NUMERDO")).size()); //1
    driver.findElement(By.id("ftMaskEdit_1_NUMERDO")).click();  
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("ftMaskEdit_1_NUMERDO")).isDisplayed()); //true
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("ftMaskEdit_1_NUMERDO")).isEnabled()); //true
```

when I try: `driver.findElement(By.id("ftMaskEdit_1_NUMERDO")).clear();` I have got an error:
NoSuchElement Exceptions Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only

when I send keys:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ftMaskEdit_1_NUMERDO")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ftMaskEdit_1_NUMERDO")).sendKeys(Keys.Home,"ABB111111')
```

nothing happen.
I try use Robot, Action and JavaScript but I still can't send the text:(
How can I send keys to this element?

Comment: Is there more than one element matching that selector?

Comment: No, only one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text box that you are attempting to interact with appears to be within an embedded object.

Selenium cannot automate anything within the `<object>` tag.. Selenium **cannot** automate any embedded elements like `<object>`, `<embed>`.

Comment: Could he use javascript execution to put the value in the field?

Comment: @Richard unfortunately, no.

Comment: what can I use instead Selenium? AutoIT?

Comment: you could try, but that's a little out-of-scope for this particular question.. you most likely have to google around or open a new question